# How to create a category in xamarin ios?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard

I want to add some methods to UITextfield class along with IBInspectable and IBDesignable properties. I can do it in objective-C but am not finding a way to do the same thing in Xamarin/C#. Can anyone help me to do this?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Xamarin offers something called `Custom Controls` as seen [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_overview/) which resembles the `IBInspectable` and `IBDesignable`. I guess you could use that?

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin (really this is on C#) what you know as `Category` in Objective-C is known as `Extension Methods`.

Extension methods allows you to add functionality to a class without subclassing it, as you might already imagined.

So for example if you want to add a method to the `UILabel` class to check for null and Empty into the text property you could do something like this:

```
public static class UILabelExtensionMethod
{
    public static bool TextIsNullOrEmpty (this UILabel label)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty (label?.Text);
    }
}
```

Now with the above you can call that method on any UILabel object

```
var myLabel = new UILabel ();

var isEmpty = myLabel.TextIsNullOrEmpty ();
```

However, Extension methods cannot be used with the `IBInspectable` and `IBDesignable` annotations. These annotations are only available when sub-classing and as @Demitrian indicated this is called [Custom Controls](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_overview/).

Hope this helps.-